Looking for a solution to a 2-dimensional recurrence relation with a floor function in GF(2)
I have a recurrence relation that i'd like to solve. It is  defined as follows:
$$ a_{i,j}  = (a_{i-1,j} + \lfloor 3  \sum_{k=0}^{j-1} \frac{a_{i-1,k}}{2^{j-k}} \rfloor \space) \bmod 2 $$
where $ a_{i,0} = 1 \space \forall \space i  $ and $ a_{0,j} = 0 \space \forall \space j > 0 $. I am aware of multivariate generating functions as a method of finding solutions to arrays of recurrences, but the occurrence of the floor function and mod 2 has really thrown me off. I'm not sure if representing the floor function as a fourier series will work.
This problems origin is related to binary representations of powers of 3 in the following way: suppose there is an infinite 2-d array where the n'th row corresponds to $3^n$ in binary. $3^n = a_{n,0} + 2a_{n,1} + ...+ 2^j a_{n,j} + ... $ and since $3^n = 2\cdot3^{n-1} + 3^{n-1} $ this naturally leads to the relation $a_{i,j} = (a_{i-1,j} + a_{i-1,j-1} + c_{i-1,j-1}) \bmod 2 $ derived from long addition where $c_{i-1,j-1}$ is a 'carry operation'. $$c_{i,j} := 
\begin{cases} 
0, & \text{if $a_{i,j} + a_{i,j-1} + c_{i,j-1} < 2$} \\
1, & \text{else}
\end{cases}
$$
But this can be replaced with $\lfloor\frac{1}{2}\hat c_{i,j} \rfloor $ where $\hat c_{i,j} := a_{i,j} + a_{i,j-1} + \frac{1}{2}\hat c_{i,j-1}$. Its not too hard to see that $$\hat c_{i,j} = a_{i,j} + \frac{3}{2}a_{i,j-1} + ... + \frac{3}{2^j}a_{i,0} $$ Plugging that in and rearranging yields the first equation.
UPDATE:
An alternative representation of the recurrence relation. I've noticed an equivalent definitionof  $c_{i,j}$ by setting $c_{i,j} = (a_{i,j}*a_{i,j-1} + c_{i,j-1}*a_{i,j} + c_{i,j-1}*a_{i,j-1}) \bmod 2$ where $*$ is just multiplication. plugging this into $a_{i,j} = (a_{i-1,j} + a_{i-1,j-1} + c_{i-1,j-1}) \bmod 2 $ and playing around with it has yielded the following:
$$a_{i,j} = (a_{i-1,j} + a_{i-1,j-2} + (a_{i-1,j-1}*a_{i-1,j-2}) + (a_{i-1,j-1}*a_{i,j-1}) + (a_{i-1,j-2}*a_{i,j-1})) \bmod 2 $$
which is clearly nonlinear. I'm not sure if its even holonomic. I've tried a separation of variables approach and got nowhere. Perhaps there is a way with matrix exponentiaion as one can generate Lah numbers and the binomial coefficients and they seem to share some indirect links to the recurrence?
